# Detecting teardown of built-in PHP server

Tags: php, terminal

Is there a way to detect if a running built-in PHP server has been stopped? Either by hitting `Ctrl-C` or just by closing the terminal window.

I'm using it for a development environment and would like to clean up some files on teardown.

Comment: will your cleanup code also run on the not yet shut down server? Or are you planning to use a seperate execution environment to do that?

Comment: I'll preventively clean up on start and clean up again on shutdown. Also, on launch, I'm initializing a file watcher to detect changes on all files in a tmp folder. With hassan's solution, I can make the file watcher detect the shutdown, perform a cleanup and shutdown itself. So that's a perfect solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, i don't know if there are exist in the php built-in server feature to do so,

but as a work around you may accomplish this using terminal,

using the `;` symbol which is used to separate two commands and in executing the second command after the first command finishes it's execution.

for example this script will add shut down line to the file status.txt only when you hit `CTRL+C` -*finishing the first command*- :

```
php -S localhost:8000 ; echo "shut down" >> status.txt
```

you may create a new php/bash script or whatever to execute specific tasks and execute it after exiting the server -after hitting `CTRL+C`

Comment: Thanks! Simple and efficient. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: There is still one thing that doesn't work. On `Ctrl+C` the file is generated. But when the terminal window is closed, the second command isn't called of course. Any way to hook into that action?

Comment: it will be more complicated , when i get back to home i will try to update my answer with this;

Answer (score 0):

You could register function which will be called on script exit by  `register_shutdown_function()`

```
register_shutdown_function(function() {/* Some cleanup activity */});
```

More sophisticated solution is to grab signal  by `pcntl_signal()`. The one from ctrl + c is `SIGINT`

```
pcntl_signal(SIGINT, "signalHandler");

function signalHandler($signal) {
    switch($signal) {
        case SIGINT:
            print "Caught SIGINT\n";
            exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: shutdown will execute when the php process end not when the server gets down or terminated;

Comment: Yes but you can wrap php built-in server with your custom starting script and in this script handle execution and different signal from system. Like in Symfony framework you're starting server by typing `app/console server:run` and this is cleanest solution i think.

Comment: using `register_shutdown_function` will execute the function every time you are refresh your page, so this is not the proper way to do though , and check the [pcntl_signal](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php) man to check if this is the prober way too ;

Comment: Right, i meant to use this as wrapper for executing server.